# Use indexed position or condition in one PySpark column to extract a value in another

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am new to PySpark/Python. I am trying to create a new column and putting a string from an array in a column that has the highest frequency in another array column.

I tried using the following

```
df.select(df.Name, df.Freq,
     expr("element_at(Name, array_position(Freq, array_max(Freq)))")
  .alias("Popular")).display()
```

to produce this:

| Name | Freq | Popular |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['AB', 'DC', 'TZ','ETC','RX'] | [1,4,1,2,2] | DC |
| ['XYS', 'FD', 'PA'] | [2,1,6] | PA |

But i get the "Column is not iterable' TypeError. My many, many trials and errors pointed me to the array_position() function. Because when I use this:

```
df.select(df.Name, df.Freq,
     expr("element_at(Name, array_max(Freq))")
  .alias("Popular")).display()
```

I produced this:

| Name | Freq | Popular |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['AB', 'DC', 'TZ','ETC','RX'] | [1,4,1,2,2] | ETC |
| ['XYS', 'FD', 'PA'] | [2,1,6] | Null |

element_at() uses the number of frequency as the position and collect the 4th element in the Name array column in the first row and NULL on the second row since the array has only 3 elements, which tells me that element_at() and array_max() work just fine.

I checked some websites, and both array_max() and array_position() use col object types. So I'm confused why array_max() work but array_position() doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the issue is the return types of these functions are different.

`array_max`

> Returns the result matches the type of the elements. NULL elements are skipped.

`array_position`

> Returns a long type.

I am guessing your current `Freq` column is integer, therefore, `array_max` will return integer type. Wheares, `array_position` will return long type.

When you are using with `element_at` function, `element_at` function requires integer value for the 2nd argument. That's why with `array_max`, it works but not with `array_position`.

#### How to fix

Cast the result of `array_position` to integer

```
df.select(df.Name, df.Freq,
          F.expr("element_at(Name, cast(array_position(Freq, array_max(Freq)) as int))").alias("Popular"))
```

Or use array syntax. With this syntax, note that array requires 0-based index and `array_position` returns in 1-based index, so add -1 to adjust the value.

```
df.select(df.Name, df.Freq,
          F.expr("Name[array_position(Freq, array_max(Freq))-1]").alias("Popular"))
```